# input[type=date] format value dynamically generated in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, date-formatting

I have an input with a value dynamically generated

```
<input name="etd" type"date" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
```

In order to support html5 date input, a date format `yyyy-mm-dd` is assigned to that value, and `mm/dd/yyyy`  format is shown in html5 browsers correctly.

The problem arises on non html5 browsers where the value assigned is shown as text directly (format `yyyy-mm-dd`). My attempt to transform this value to format `mm/dd/yyyy` with *jQuery* is the following:

```
<script>
    $('input[type="date"]').each({  

        var now = new Date($(this).attr('value'));
        var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);     
        var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);        
        $(this).val(today);

    }); 
</script>
```

but is not working, I'm new to *jQuery*, so I think, it's something with it.

UPDATE:

I'm using this code to put a date picker on non html5 capable browsers, this not solves my problem with the dates retrieved from database, but the if clause somehow can difference html5 browsers. I thinking maybe I can use that condition to filter the jQuery code (that code which i'm looking for)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes['date']) {
            $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: $(this).va() instead of $(this).attr('value')

Comment: I saw that, but either way works for getting the value, but the code didn't get executed, when I put an alert in it, it didn't pop. Thanks

Comment: You can test `<input>` supports `type="date"` using `'valueAsDate' in HTMLInputElement.prototype`

Comment: It `type"date"` a typo?

Comment: yes, it is a typo... the actual input has the right format. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like;
Here's the [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/9qm8d16t/68/).

Html:

```
<input name="etd" type="date" value="1919-03-12">
```

Js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('input[type=date]').each(function (this){  

       var datestring = $(this).val(); 
       var dateobj    = new Date(datestring);

       var formattedstring = dateobj.getUTCDate()+"/"+dateobj.getUTCMonth()+"/"+dateobj.getUTCFullYear();

       $(this).val(formattedstring);

    });

});
```

Also please note that when you set the **date** and **month** values, for single values there should be a zero in front of it. For example month 7 should be 07.

Btw, in your code you are missing the **=** sign in **type"date"** please correct that too :)

Comment: Hi Laky, I think you hit the right spot. I was trouble by the fact the input has already values (and some others, not), and the other answers did not count on that. But the problem now is that I have to do it only in browsers that NOT support html5, I think the comment from Paul S. would do the trick, but I have to try it first.

Comment: Hi @culebrin I think you can check this link for html5 support. http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#input-types

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can actually use `split` on the string. Much easier than passing it through the Date object.

```
$('input[type="date"]').each(function(){  

    var now = $(this).attr('value').split("-");
    var today = now[1]+"/"+now[2]+"/"+now[0]; //mm/dd/yyyy        
    $(this).val(today);

});
```

`split` will hack a string into array pieces using the delimiter. A dash in this case. The following array is created:

```
['yyyy', 'mm', 'dd'];
```

Now you can rearrange those array pieces into the desired string.

A demo:

```js
$('input[type="date"]').each(function(){  

    var now = $(this).attr('value').split("-");
    var today = now[1]+"/"+now[2]+"/"+now[0]; //mm/dd/yyyy        
    $(this).val(today);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="2015-08-09" />
```

Comment: this code gets me an error: "SyntaxError: missing : after property id". I'm guessing the $('input[type="date"]').each line syntax is not right

Comment: Nope your original function had a bug. `function()` missing inside the `each`.